# Delphi - using selstart and sellength, but with cursor in the left (selstart position) instead end (sellength position)

Tags: delphi, position, cursor, edit, right-to-left

I'm using Delphi to develop a DBLookupComboBox component with your own SQL (using Devart UniDac), without external ListSource, ListField, KeyField. Everything is working perfectly fine, but for a better user interface, I need one small detail.

I always leave the selected text according to the user's typing. When characters are typed, all right; but, when movement keys are typed (VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT, combinations and etc.), the process is not cool, because the SelStart/SelLength places the cursor at the end of the text (sellength) and I want the cursor in the left (at SelStart), next to the last letter typed.

The component (using TFrame, TEdit and etc).

[image]

User typed BIAN, my component find the first person and use SelStart/SelLength to highlight.

[image]

User typed VK_LEFT, my component should show this:

[image]

But show this:

[image]

Comment: You have to post enough code for someone else to reproduce the problem.  Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How are we supposed to be able to explain why what you're doing won't work when we can't see the code you're using? Post a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the problem, or we can't help you. Saying My code isn't working right, but I won't show you my code. What's wrong? simply does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the `SelStart`/`SelLength` properties to not support what you are asking for.  [Despite what MSDN documentation claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661.aspx), the caret is always placed on the right side of the selection.

However, there is a simple trick you can use to place the caret on the left side of the selection instead:

```
procedure SelectText(Edit: TCustomEdit; iFirst, iLast: Integer);
var
  bState: TKeyboardState;
  bNewState: TKeyboardState;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if iFirst <= iLast then begin
    {
    Edit.SelStart := iFirst;
    Edit.SelLength := iLast - iFirst;
    }
    SendMessage(Edit.Handle, EM_SETSEL, iFirst, iLast);
  end else
  begin
    //Edit.SelStart := iFirst;
    SendMessage(Edit.Handle, EM_SETSEL, iFirst, iFirst);
    if GetKeyboardState(bState) then
    begin
      bNewState := bState;
      bNewState[VK_SHIFT] := bNewState[VK_SHIFT] or 128;
      if SetKeyboardState(bNewState) then
      begin
        repeat
          SendMessage(Edit.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_LEFT, 0);
          Dec(iFirst);
        until iFirst = iLast;
        SendMessage(Edit.Handle, WM_KEYUP, VK_LEFT, 0);
        SetKeyboardState(bState);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure SelectText(Edit: TEdit; iFirst, iLength: Integer);
var
  bState: TKeyboardState;
  bNewState: TKeyboardState;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if iLength >= 0 then begin
    {
    Edit.SelStart := iFirst;
    Edit.SelLength := iLength;
    }
    SendMessage(Edit.Handle, EM_SETSEL, iFirst, iFirst + iLength);
  end else
  begin
    //Edit.SelStart := iFirst;
    SendMessage(Edit.Handle, EM_SETSEL, iFirst, iFirst);
    if GetKeyboardState(bState) then
    begin
      bNewState := bState;
      bNewState[VK_SHIFT] := bNewState[VK_SHIFT] or 128;
      if SetKeyboardState(bNewState) then
      begin
        repeat
          SendMessage(Edit.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_LEFT, 0);
          Inc(iLength);
        until iLength = 0;
        SendMessage(Edit.Handle, WM_KEYUP, VK_LEFT, 0);
        SetKeyboardState(bState);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Depending on whether you want to define the selection using absolute start/end positions, or a start position and a length.

Basically, what this code is doing is if the ending position is lower than the starting position, the code places the caret at the starting right side position and then simulates <kbd>Shift+Left</kbd> key presses until the caret reaches the desired left side position.

Comment: Thank you, very much! Worked perfectly!
Just a comment for ease of use to others:
When calling the above function, place the highest value as iFirst and the lowest as iLast. Ie SelectText (Edit, SelLength, SelStart)

Comment: @FashionStrada the function allows both left-to-right and right-to-left selections.